# What is the most grammatically correct sentence for a warning message for a date comparison?

Tags: validation, date, grammar

Which one of these expressions is the most correct one or the most common one?

- From Date cannot be larger than To Date
- From Date cannot be greater than To Date
- From Date cannot be after To Date

Comment: This is probably going to get closed as it isn't really a programming question, but I would personally write "From Date cannot be after To Date"

Comment: Why should it be closed? Did I miss some rule?

Comment: Generally the questions here are about programming problems [[see the StackOverflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)]. You question might be better suited in one of the other Stack Exchange forums such as [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/?as=1), [English Language](http://english.stackexchange.com/?as=1) or [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/?as=1). It is nothing personal and I think you would get a better / more comprehensive answer from one of those forums.

Comment: Http://English.stackexchange.com would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the validation message should be -'From' Date cannot be later than 'To' Date

Comment: That sounds quite good. How come it did not pop up in my mind =)